# Retrieve nodes by their relationship to another node

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

This is my Neomodel class:

```
class Sample(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)


class Annots(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()    
    attributedTo = RelationshipTo('Sample', 'attributedTo', OneOrMore)
    assignedBy = RelationshipFrom('User', 'assignedBy', OneOrMore)
```

The user selects a sample, so I need to retrive all anotations that are linked to that sample.
Using Cquery is straightforward:

```
MATCH (a:Annots)-[r:attributedTo]->(s:Sample)
where s.name = 'x'
RETURN a
```

But when I run into Python Neomodel I just can't figure out how to make it other than this and it seems not the right way.

```
current_sample = Sample.nodes.first_or_none(name=samples[selected_sample])
if current_sample is not None:
    related_annots = Annots.nodes.all(attributedTo=current_sample)
```

> ValueError: No such property attributedTo on Annots. Note that Neo4j
> internals like id or element_id are not allowed for use in this
> operation.

I have thought of loading all annots nodes and then iterate to check their attribute but I don't think it is the best solution.
Also I can change the relationship to Sample class, but I think it is better located in Annots class.

Any thoughts here?

--------- Update ---------

I can solve it by changing the Sample class to:

```
class Sample(StructuredNode):
    uid = UniqueIdProperty()
    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True)
    attributedfrom = RelationshipFrom('Annots', 'attributedTo', OneOrMore)
```

and making this filter call:

```
related_annots = current_sample.attributedfrom.all()
```

Still not convinced this is the propoer way to get around thisproblem